# Parking Simulator how to create and report ticket

Tags: java, arrays, methods, associations

Sorry to put all this code out here but I am stuck and have been for days.  I am having trouble creating the for loop in the Parking Simulator. I dont even know where to start.  I have searched google and I havent found any Parking simulators that used array lists. Here are the requirements:

The ParkingSimulator Class: This class should simulate checking the parking tickets.  You should loop through the cars, choose a random officer, and have that officer check to see if there is a parking violation.  If there is a violation, add it to the ParkingTicket ArrayList.  After all have been checked, print out a summary of the tickets (using the toString() from the ParkingTicket class).

I think I have all the classes right except for the ParkingTicket Class which I know is screwed up in the for loop because I cannot get the random officer and create and report ticket if mins were over maxlimit and it is printing the whole string of officers when it should be picking one officer at random to assign to the ticket. Also it is not printing out the whole output.

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at parking.ParkingTicket.reportTicket(ParkingTicket.java:19)
at parking.ParkingSimulator.main(ParkingSimulator.java:34)
```

output should look like:

VW with license # N34234 parked for 60 minutes at PM1 and a maximum time limit of 90 minutes - no violation.
Reported by officer Joe badge: PO123

Mazda with license # 234-567 parked for 70 minutes at PM2 and a maximum time limit of 60 minutes
was parked illegally for 10 minutes for a fine of 25.0. 
Reported by officer Sam badge: PO812

etc;

Summary of tickets:
License:234-567 at meter #:PM2: Fine: $25.00

License:W879HY4 at meter #:PM4: Fine: $25.00

License:BG65RF7 at meter #:PM5: Fine: $25.00

etc;

This should be the logic of main in ParkingSimulator

```
    // create four ArrayLists.  One for each class
    // create random number generator that will be used to decide which officer will be assigned

    // load initial data by calling my method
    // loop through the parked cars arraylist
    // select a random officer            
    // output parked car information
    // calculate the number of minutes of violation (the number of minutes for the car minus the maximum for the meter             
    // if number of minutes of violation is greater than zero
     //create a ticket
     //report ticket
     // and add the ticket to parking ticket arraylist 
    //else 
    // output that there is no violation
    // print out the officer that reported this check

   // end loop

    // output ticket summary
    System.out.println("\nSummary of tickets:");
    // loop through the ticket arraylist and output tickets

    }

}
```

parking simulator class

Here is where I am having trouble in the loop.

```
package parking;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ParkingSimulator {

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<PoliceOfficer> po= new ArrayList<PoliceOfficer>();
    ArrayList<ParkingMeter> pm= new ArrayList<ParkingMeter>();
    ArrayList<ParkedCar> pc= new ArrayList<ParkedCar>();
    ArrayList<ParkingTicket> pt= new ArrayList<ParkingTicket>();

     // create random number generator that will be used to decide which officer will be assigned
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    loadData(po,pm,pc);

    for(int i=0;i<pc.size();i++){

    // select a random officer 
        int a=rand.nextInt(po.size());
        // output parked car information
        System.out.println(pc.get(i).toString());
        // calculate the number of minutes of violation (the number of minutes for the car minus the maximum for the meter             
        int min=pm.get(i).getNumMinsMax()-pc.get(i).getNumberOfMinutesParked();
        // if number of minutes of violation is greater than zero
        if(min >0){            
    //create a ticket
            ParkingTicket ticket = new ParkingTicket();

            ticket.reportTicket();//report ticket

    // and add the ticket to parking ticket arraylist
            pt.add(ticket);
        }     
        else{
    System.out.println("There is no violation.");
        }
        // print out the officer that reported this check
        System.out.println(po.toString());

// end loop
    }

    System.out.println("\nSummary of tickets:");
    // loop through the ticket arraylist and output tickets
    for (int i=0;i<pt.size();i++)
    System.out.println(pt.get(i).toString());
}

public static void loadData(ArrayList<PoliceOfficer> po, ArrayList<ParkingMeter> pm, ArrayList<ParkedCar> pc) {

    po.add(new PoliceOfficer("Joe", "PO123"));
    po.add(new PoliceOfficer("Mike", "PO866"));
    po.add(new PoliceOfficer("Suzie", "PO956"));
    po.add(new PoliceOfficer("Sam", "PO812"));

    pm.add(new ParkingMeter(90,"PM1"));
    pm.add(new ParkingMeter(60,"PM2"));
    pm.add(new ParkingMeter(30,"PM3"));
    pm.add(new ParkingMeter(10,"PM4"));
    pm.add(new ParkingMeter(90,"PM5"));
    pm.add(new ParkingMeter(60,"PM6"));

    pc.add(new ParkedCar("VW", "N34234",60,pm.get(0)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Mazda", "234-567",70,pm.get(1)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Subaru", "HelloKitty",45,pm.get(2)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Buick", "W879HY4",20,pm.get(3)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Miata", "BG65RF7",125,pm.get(4)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Corvette", "JI9987",10,pm.get(5)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Chevy", "12AS76",145,pm.get(1)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("VW", "MK987",170,pm.get(2)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Dodge", "JR4534D",86,pm.get(3)));
    pc.add(new ParkedCar("Ford", "C56FDS",60,pm.get(4)));

}
}
```

parkingticket class

```
package parking;

public class ParkingTicket {
private ParkedCar pc;
private PoliceOfficer po;
private ParkingMeter pm;
private int minsOver;
private double fine;

public void ParkingTicket(){
}

public void ParkingTicket(ParkedCar pc,PoliceOfficer po,int mo){
    minsOver=mo;

}

public void reportTicket(){
     if (pc.getNumberOfMinutesParked() > pm.getNumMinsMax())
// Determine the amount of the fine.
         minsOver=pc.getNumberOfMinutesParked() - pm.getNumMinsMax();
if (minsOver <= 60)
fine = 25;
else
fine = 25 + (10 * (minsOver / 60));

    if(minsOver <0){
                 System.out.println("No Violation");
            }

}

public ParkedCar getPc() {
    return pc;
}

public void setPc(ParkedCar pc) {
    this.pc = pc;
}

public PoliceOfficer getPo() {
    return po;
}

public void setPo(PoliceOfficer po) {
    this.po = po;
}

public String toString(){
    return " was illegally parked for "+minsOver+" for a fine of "+fine;
}

}
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code and post what's important.

Comment: I am mainly focused on the for loop in the parking simulator I just put all the code because I need to access these different classes

Comment: This code - int min=pm.get(i).getNumMinsMax()-pc.get(i).getNumberOfMinutesParked(); will give you a negative number if the car has been parked longer than the meter max.  Like 60-80 = -20 is a violation.  You then check if (min>0) for a violation which doesn't correspond.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I cannot change the constructor as that is what is required in the uml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the new ParkingTicket() you do it via the no-argument constructor.  Next you call the ParkingTicket.reportTicket() method which references pc and pm.  At that point pc and pm have never been set - which causes a nullPointerException.  Looks like your code is set up to set these via the constructor that does have arguments.

public void ParkingTicket(ParkedCar pc,PoliceOfficer po,int mo){
    minsOver=mo;

}

But even that won't work in the state it is currently in because it doesn't set pc or pm.

Comment: Ok so I fixed the error where I was subtracting wrong but now am still confused with the report of the ticket not sure where I am supposed to set pc and pm

Comment: Fix your the constructor that has arguments and pass pc and pm when creating a new ParkingTicket() object.